# Rails Aws Assets compiling issue - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, capistrano, precompile

After very very very hard work, I am successful in deploying to aws using following tutorial.
[tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/?utm_source=sitepoint&utm_medium=relatedsidebar&utm_term=ruby)

Now my homepage shows but my assets are not rending and I don't see any stylesheet. By seeing page source, when I click application.css file, Nginx gives 404 error i.e file not found.

I have spent alot of time to figure it out. Tried to compile assets manually, changed the capistrano configuration but still no success. My site is at
[My Site](http://ec2-52-33-168-138.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/users/sign_in). When capistrano is uploading files, it does show execution of precompiling but I don't see the result.
I tried to see logs of nginx file but I cannot find its file to see exactly if I have error there.

someone please give me some suggestion. My assets folder has permission number 4.

Comment: You have to either turn off prod mode in your rails config, or you have to configure nginx to serve static files for you. The reason is when prod mode is turned on in rails, it relies on the web server instead of the application server to serve static files. And then check if it works

Comment: How to turn off production mode. By commenting "config.serve_static_files = true " and "config.assets.compile = false" these lines or someother way??? I have tried commenting these lines as well.

Comment: Did you check out this thread? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150904